Detect whether items in a ReorderableListView have moved around as you are dragging an item
Is there a way to detect whether items in a ReorderableListView have shifted while you are actively reordering an item (still dragging it)?
ReorderableListView(
onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {},   
children: [
_CustomWidget(0),
_CustomWidget(1),     
_CustomWidget(2),   
] 
);

If _CustomWidget(1) were dragged above _CustomWidget(0) but not dropped there, would it be possible to detect that _CustomWidget(1) and _CustomWidget(2) shifted? I know if _CustomWidget(1) were dragged and dropped above _CustomWidget(0), the onReorder callback would be fired, but is there something similar for just a drag?
